# android dp size for LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to add some centered elements to a LinearLayout(like textViews or buttons). If I use  android:layout_width="fill_parent" the button can be too big on a large screen like a tablet. So I am thinking to limit the width on larger screens.

I use this

```
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"

             android:layout_width="310dp"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:paddingBottom ="60dp"
             android:paddingTop ="10dp"
             android:paddingLeft ="5dp"
             android:paddingRight ="5dp"
             android:id="@+id/linear_id"

             >


             ...............


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

From what I see the smallest screen size for Android is 320dp
This layout will be displayed ok on any small screen or do you think I could have problems on some devices? I have set the width to 310dp and the total padding is 10dp so in total it should be 320dp.

Thanks

Comment: did you tried max-width?

Comment: If you want to limit the Button size as half of the screen or some percentage then use weight in your layout.

Comment: Thank you for your answers but the layout is looks ok. I am just asking if I could have problems on some phones(where the layout is not displayed properly). I will change the layout only if I could have problems

Answer (score 0):

Replace **dp** with **sdp**(scalable dp). This scales with the screen size. It can help you with supporting multiple screens.

Add this dependency in your gradle.

`compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2'`

Use like this:-
`android:paddingLeft ="@dimen/_5sdp"`

Also use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` in `LinearLayout`'s `Height`/`Width`

Hope this will help you.... :) :)