# 320dp for a android layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

In Android is it ok do set the width of a linear layout to 320dp? Can it be to big for some small screens?

On the internet people say that 320dp is the smallest android screen, but I just want to ask if someone tested this. Thanks

This question is related to [android dp size for LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262284/android-dp-size-for-linearlayout) but nobody answered the question so I wanted to try to ask the question in a different way

Comment: Yeah, it must be so. But it has Chinese devices with not standart screens. So, I recomend u to not set more that 240 dp size.

Comment: Ask yourself if you really need setting width of layout to fixed number. How about match_parent, wrap_content, or using percentages? You can of course use different dimens.xml for different screens, but usually you can prevent that.

Comment: https://material.io/devices/ for the standard devices I see that only watches have a smaller dp

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi layout files as [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) for small and large screens.
We have 2 positions (landscape and portrait) and 2 sizes (normal and large) of screen. So, there are 4 types of layout.

```
res/
    layout/              # default (portrait)
        main.xml
    layout-land/         # landscape
        main.xml
    layout-large/        # large (portrait)
        main.xml
    layout-large-land/   # large landscape
        main.xml
```

You have to create layout file with same name in them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fixed size you should try `match_parent` vs `wrap_content`.

> On the internet people say that 320dp is the smallest android screen

Smallest device that I know is `240dp x 320dp`  which means 240dp is the smallest device size.

See following links for clarity

[What is the difference between match_parent and fill_parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent)

[Supporting Different Screen Sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

http://www.randomlytyping.com/blog/2014/2/9/matchparent-vs-fillparent

[ViewGroup.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

**Update**

Smallest device can have resolution of `180px x 240px` = `240dp x 320dp`

[image]

Comment: `240px != 240dp`. As rule, 240x320 px devices use ldpi so `320dp * 0,75 = 240px`

Comment: yeah, i see, and?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think that 240x320 is not in dp. It is important how you measure that value. 2560x1600 is for sure not dp

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Configuration examples

To help you target some of your designs for different types of devices, here are some numbers for typical screen widths:

    320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
    480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
    600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
    720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

this is what they say

Comment: it says that devices that has this resolution (in pixels), as rule, have XXX pixels per inch (or dots per inch). I.e. 240x320 pixels has 120 dpi.